# Display an image in silverlight datagrid

Tags: wcf, xaml, silverlight-3.0

How would i display an image in my silverlight datagrid from the database using WCF please help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn Width="25">
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Width="20" Stretch="Fill" Source="../Images/img.png" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
         <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Image">
                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="3,12,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"  Source="{Binding Image1}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

Code Behind

public partial class MainPage: UserControl

{

public  MainPage()

{

InitializeComponent();

ObservableCollection MyListItem = new ObservableCollection();
  MyListItem.Add(new ListItems {Image1 = new BitmapImage(new Uri    ("/SilverlightApplication2;component/Images/Capture.JPG",UriKind.Relative)) });

dataGrid1.ItemsSource = MyListItem;

}

}

public class ListItems

{

public BitmapImage Image1 { get; set; }

}